# JQuery Validation plugin: input textbox content validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I'm using the JQuery Validation plugin http://jqueryvalidation.org/ and I have the following scenario:

Example HTML:

```
   <input type="text" name="glass_name"  id="glass_name">
   <input type="text" name="glass_name_confirm"  id="glass_name_confirm">
```

Example Javascript:

```
      $("#form").validate({
        rules: {
            glass_name: {
                required: true
            },
            glass_name_confirm: {
                required: true,
                equalTo: "#glass_name"
            },
```

How can I validate the input box content against a string words array?. For instance, I don't want that the user in the textbox id=glass_name insert a list of innapropiate words: word1 or word2 or word3, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a custom rule:

//Add new method:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("validationFilterWords", function(value, element) {
var arrFilter = ["Word1","Word2"];
    return this.optional(element) || ($.inArray(value,arrFilter) === -1);
}, "* Not allowed");
```

// Add new rule

```
 rules : {
        glass_name: {
                      validationFilterWords: true,
                      required: true

                     }
    }
```

Comment: Great, glad to help. You might want accept the answer then.